# Jquery POST sending data in GET format

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this javascript in my page.

```
function save() {
    // submit the dataform
    s = document.dataform.action.split('?');
    d = s[1]+'&'+$("#dataform").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: s[0],
        data: d,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: handleReply
    });
}
```

It is called when I want to submit the form (and handle the reply using AJAX). However although $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] is indeed "POST" when it arrives at the server, all the data arrives in the $_GET variable! :(

I have screens with more than 2K of data so I have to find how to POST the data using the normal (and unlimited) POST method.

I had a version with the url and data lines as

```
url: document.dataform.action,
data: new FormData(document.dataform),
```

This worked superbly with some data arriving from the action in $_GET and the rest from screen fields arriving in $_POST. Then I tested it using IE8 and IE9, which don't support FormData.

Can anyone suggest how I can modify the code to work in IE8 and IE9 and use POST transfer logic.

Thanks

Comment: why is contentType false and processData false?

Comment: Docs: [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already been requested by a GET.

Comment: IIRC, that was the way the example was written that I copy/pasted when I first set this up months ago. (Adding IE8 is a new idea).